# Add param to url path with subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to get this url:

blog.example.com/12

i have this:

```
<%= link_to post.title, root_url(:subdomain => "blog")  %>
```

this gives me blog.example.com, how can I add the 12 at the end that is the post.id

Edit:

I found a way to fix this, but to me it looks like a hack, this is what I did:

```
<%= link_to post.title, root_url(:subdomain => "blog")+post.id.to_s  %>
```

If anyone finds a more elegant solution, let me know !

Comment: why not do this in routes.rb?

Comment: can you elaborate? I have this in my routes.rb: match '/:id', :to => 'posts#show', :constraints =>  lambda {|r| r.subdomain.present?  && r.subdomain == 'blog'}

Comment: You are not passing any `id` in your `link_to`. Try `root_url(id: post.id, subdomain: 'blog')`

Comment: @Abm this dosnt work either, it returns this: blog.example.com/?id=12

Comment: How about `root_url(post, subdomain: 'blog')`? I am just trying to draw on the similarity with `show` or `edit` actions.

Comment: @AbM yeah, ive tried that and gives me this error: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

Comment: i did a fix, i edited my question, looks like a hack but for now its working